# Pass ViewModel to User Control Constructor from XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, dependency-injection

In my MVVM application, I am trying to create a reusable user control that's been shared between multiple applications, here's the constructor

```
public MyUserControl(IMyViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = viewModel;
}
```

So my plan is that each application will just feed it's own viewmodel to the shared view.

Now the questions is how to pass viewmodel object from XAML code to the constructor:

```
<my:MyUserControl "somehow pass a viewmodel object from here">
```

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't, you need a parameterless constructor.  The best you can do is bind directly:

```
<my:MyUserControl DataContext="{Binding Path.To.ViewModel}">
```

Actually, I'm not entirely right.  In WPF 4, you can using an [arguments directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee795382.aspx).  But I really wouldn't, it's not really idiomatic WPF.